# Киевляне присягнули, и через несколько дней после сего изменили. Почему здесь запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, однородные-члены

*Киевляне присягнули, и через несколько дней после сего изменили, тайно предложив Изяславу Мстиславичу занять место Игоря.* Чем обосновывается в данном случае запятая перед И? (конечно, если поставить тире, то понятно, что обосновывается оно неожиданной сменой событий)

- Аналогичный пример. *Дети читали книги и играли с игрушками, пели песенки и танцевали под музыку, и всегда радовались приходу няни.* (или: *и всегда помогали друг другу*.)
- Много раз встречала такие случаи, когда перед И, которое соединяет однородные сказуемые с зависимыми словами или без них, вдруг стоит запятая. Она действительно просится, особенно когда сообщение, передаваемое предикатом, выражает некоторый итог, вывод или имеет добавочный, присоединительный характер (вроде, все сказано, но вот это тоже уместно сказать), но при этом до полноценного присоединительного предложения как бы не дотягивает (или дотягивает?) Нет ли какого-то конкретного правила на сей счет?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Если ориентироваться **на правила пунктуации,** то союз И в этих случаях считается **присоединительным.**

2) Если ориентироваться **на грамматику** (и это более правильный подход), то между однородными сказуемыми **нет тесной связи** (по смыслу или по структуре предложения), поэтому мы считаем, что это **сложное предложение** с пропущенным подлежащим во второй части.

**Киевляне присягнули, и через несколько дней после сего (они) изменили, тайно предложив Изяславу Мстиславичу занять место Игоря.**

Второе предложение осложненное, между сказуемыми находится обстоятельство.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! А какой знак предпочтительнее в данном случае: запятая с приведенным обоснованием или тире?

Comment: В этом предложении сложно сделать увеличенную паузу, соответствующую тире.  Сравнить: Киевляне присягнули –  и изменили уже через несколько дней.

Comment: Это *и* кажется мне не очень уместным. Почему бы не поставить *а*? Как говорил Остап, "Будьте проще и к вам потянутся люди".

Comment: Это то, что называется неожиданным присоединением. Вавила бросил что-то в костёр, притоптал — и тотчас же стало очень темно (Ч.).  http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=135#pp135